Webshop: Edit prices of goods with multiple properties and volume discount
In a web shop, goods are sold that have one property (e.g. size). Each variant should have a separate price. Also, they can have volume discounts at user-defined thresholds.
At the moment, the price editing looks like this:



Shirt







Price scale
1
10
Click here to add more columns


Size S
10
9.5



Size M
11
10



Size L
12
11




Now goods can have have multiple properties (e.g. color, size, shape). Each variant should have a different price with different volume discounts. With just two more properties, each with two variants, this would look like this:



Shirt







Price scale
1
10
Click here to add more columns


Size S, red, slim
10.5
9.5



Size S, red, loose
10
9



Size S, blue, slim
9
9.5



Size S, blue, loose
8
7.5



Size M, red, slim
10
9.5



Size M, red, loose
10
9.5



Size L, blue, slim
10
9.5



Size L, blue, loose
10
9.5




Obviously this gets out of control very fast.
How can I modify the price configuration to allow for an arbitrary number of properties with an arbitrary number of variants without making the table super long?

Tbh, maximum flexibility is achievable with such a granular table as you showed above.
If you are willing to tradeoff flexibility - by a bit - I do have one suggestion:

Allow Pricing Tiers for different volumes. In your example, TShirt can be the base entity, with 1, 10, 100 being 3 pricing tiers.
Have Size, Color, Fit etc as Modifiers. When a user selects a modifier, the final price of the item changes based on the selected modifier.


This approach do make things scalable. And many SAASs do opt for this approach. But yes, this do come with a drawback that – a "pattern" of pricing needs to be devised.

Thanks you, I think your suggestion to separate tiers from variants would be the way if reducing the pricing options is OK. This is e.g. how Ebay "Cockpit Pro" does it (although they still have a long table of all possible variant combinations and not separate UI elements like in your example).

The root cause for "this gets out of control" is the fact that all the variability is thrown into one column in an relatively unstructured string, e.g., "Size M, red, slim":

"Size M" contains the label, "red" doesn't (it should be "Color red")
The user has no control over the visibility and sequence of the dimensions
There's no grouping to help the eye find the next group.

You can improve each of these problems:

Create one column for each dimension (i.e., Size, Color, Fit) with the proper column label, and only the value in the table cell
Give the user the freedom to (quickly) choose which columns to view in which sequence
Use sorting and indentation to create (sub)groups. Do not repeat identical values from previous row (or use a lighter font), creating a visual hierarchy which helps the user to spot the next (sub)group.

I hope I am making myself clear even without a visual... :-)
